# forever is not working as expected after closing terminal or console

Tags: node.js, api, node-modules, forever

I have installed forever on shared hosting Cpanel for node js application when I run **forever start app.js**,  node js application works on the server.

```
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
info:    Forever processing file: app.js
```

But when I close terminal or console then node app stopped working. Any suggestions around it?

Comment: Also tried with nohup node app.js &

Answer (score 0):

Closing the terminal will typically close the application running. Consider using tmux or screen to launch the app or also nohup.

Launching this way should be considered a short-term solution. You probably want to look at how your specific Linux distribution handles startup scripts and services.

Answer (score 0):

like maldina said closing forever will stop your app consider
consider upstart (it runs tasks when the computer is started)
you basiclly create a conf file and place it in your init folder ***"var/etc/init"***
the file content should look like this

```js
#!upstart
description "my-app"

start on started mountall
stop on shutdown

# Automatically Respawn:
respawn
respawn limit 99 5

env NODE_ENV=production

exec node /somepath/myapp/server.js >> /var/log/myapp.log 2>&1
```

you can use the following commands to manage your app

```
sudo start my-app
sudo stop my-app
sudo restart my-app
```